# Windows 7 freezes when hitting Enter key in Rgui.exe

Tags: r, windows-7, freeze, rdp, rgui

I'm having a persistent problem with Windows 7 freezing when using R.  There is a specific context this happens in:

1. Using Windows 7 on a desktop machine with multiple displays, and having one or more Rgui.exe sessions running
2. Connecting to the active Windows desktop session via RDP (remote desktop), which results in resizing the display
3. Using R while connected via RDP (I'm not sure this step is actually involved.)
4. Getting back on the desktop machine and using the multiple displays again, which results in another display resizing
5. Then, I can type into an Rgui.exe window, and can type and edit a command, but when I hit Enter, the entire Windows session freezes, and all I can do is reboot.

This happens to me somewhere around 1 out of 2 or 3 times that I use the computer in the above sequence.  Sometimes it works fine, other times it freezes.  I've not noticed any pattern.  I have not noticed that there is much output in the Rgui window when this happens -- I think it can happen with a pretty fresh session.  I say this because there is [one other report on stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540211/windows-7-becomes-unresponsive-if-mouse-scroll-wheel-is-used-after-a-simulation) [Windows 7 becomes unresponsive if mouse scroll wheel is used after a simulation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540211/windows-7-becomes-unresponsive-if-mouse-scroll-wheel-is-used-after-a-simulation) of R apparently causing Windows 7 to freeze when there is a lot of output in the Rgui window.

Symptoms of the frozen machine are:

1. The text cursor in Rgui remains at the end of the line, i.e., there is no visible indication that Enter was typed
2. The mouse pointer on the screen responds to mouse movements (but not clicks) for a few seconds, but then stops responding to anything
3. The physical mouse and keyboard go dead (i.e., the mouse light on an optical mouse turns off, the caps lock light stops lighting)
4. The machine continues responds to ping
5. The machine continues to serve up any shared files and directories
6. If cygwin is installed and sshd is running, I can start up an remote shell on the machine and it works fine
7. The machine can be rebooted using a remote shutdown command from another machine
8. There is no record in any system logs of any problem relating to the freeze, or any event related to R

This has been happening to me for several years now, across multiple versions of R.  I am currently using R 3.0.2 and it just happened now.  It has happened to me at two different workplaces.

The only thing that I can do to be able to use the machine again is reboot it, either by pressing the power button, or doing a remote shutdown.  Ctrl-Alt-Delete on the keyboard has no effect.

If anyone else has encountered this problem and found a solution, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I believe this thread should be posted on http://superuser.com

Comment: Why superuser.com?  Is this question inappropriate for stackexchange?  Or do you think there is a better chance of an answer on superuser.com?

Comment: no threads are inappropriate as long as they aren't offensive. I mean there is a better chance for a relevant answer on the other forum.